# Static and dynamic text view adding simultaneously in android

Tags: android, dynamic, static, android-linearlayout

I am adding a Static and Dynamic text view simultaneously in android.but there is something wrong in the code..it is only adding the last element of array..Can You please help me to sort it out?

```
dynamicInput = (String[]) data;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                String[] string = { "Customer Mobile No :", "Nick Name :",
                        "Amount :", "Due date :" };
                LinearLayout findViewById = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicInputbiller);
                TextView dynamicText = new TextView(PayBiller_Activity.this);
                TextView staticText = new TextView(PayBiller_Activity.this);
                for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

                    staticText.setText(string[i]);

                    staticText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    staticText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);

                    dynamicText.setText(dynamicInput[i]);

                    dynamicText.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    dynamicText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
                }
                findViewById.addView(staticText);
                findViewById.addView(dynamicText);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you loop  for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
it will set only last value to the text view..what do you want exatly..

Comment: without loop how can I add array element in layout?

Comment: ok i posted my answer check it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is something different. What you are doing is that you are adding the elemnt of a array in a single TextView. And as you are doing it in a loop it is only taking the last element and fetching it in Text view. Do one thing take the ID of parent layout (Linear/relative).

**Within the loop**

create a Textview and add a value to it(the way you are doing like setText, setTextSize etc). And within the loop add it to its parent layout.

This will might help you.

Comment: OP will be notified when u have posted an answer... no need to post comment under question everytime u answers...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dynamicInput = (String[]) data;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                String[] string = { "Customer Mobile No :", "Nick Name :",
                        "Amount :", "Due date :" };
                LinearLayout findViewById = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicInputbiller);

                for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                    TextView dynamicText = new TextView(PayBiller_Activity.this);
                    TextView staticText = new TextView(PayBiller_Activity.this);
                    staticText.setText(string[i]);

                    staticText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    staticText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);

                   dynamicText.setText(dynamicInput[i]);

                    dynamicText.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    dynamicText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);

                    findViewById.addView(staticText);
                    findViewById.addView(dynamicText);
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but It is crashing if i add them inside for loop.

Comment: I am getting error like this.....java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: @Parinita Does findViewById  (dynamicInputbiller) already have child views in the xml?

Comment: <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dynamicInputbiller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
THis is my XML

Comment: @Parinita are you sure you added these lines to inside the loop?  TextView dynamicText = new TextView(PayBiller_Activity.this);
                    TextView staticText = new TextView(PayBiller_Activity.this); Have a look at my code again..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :) Actually it worked when I add the layout inside the for loop..

Answer (score 0):

put this inside your for loop.

```
findViewById.addView(staticText);
findViewById.addView(dynamicText);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but It is crashing if i add them inside for loop.

Comment: can you post your logcat.

Comment: I am getting error like this.....java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set all the array elements to your textViews then you must append it on each iteration. right now you are not doing it. hence you are getting only the last array element.

Note: also make sure your string Array dynamicInput and string array for staticText have same number of elements so that you wont get index out of bound exception or you might miss some elements while assigning it to TextView.

**I have given some other name to your "string" array. its "staticStringArray."**

```
dynamicInput = (String[]) data;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            String[] staticStringArray= { "Customer Mobile No :", "Nick Name :","Amount :", "Due date :" };
            LinearLayout findViewById = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicInputbiller);
            TextView dynamicText = new TextView(PayBiller_Activity.this);
            TextView staticText = new TextView(PayBiller_Activity.this);
            for (int i = 0; i < staticStringArray.length; i++) {

                //append each element of the array on each iteration. 
                staticText.setText(staticText.getText().toString() + staticStringArray[i] + "\n");

                staticText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                staticText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);

                //append each element of the array on each iteration. 
                dynamicText.setText(dynamicText.getText().toString() + dynamicInput[i] + "\n");

                dynamicText.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                dynamicText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
            }
            findViewById.addView(staticText);
            findViewById.addView(dynamicText);

        }
    });
```

Comment: The Array element is same for both..I am getting error like this.....java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: It looks like you have accepted an answer. i have tested the above code and it works. that illegalStateException might be for some other reason. anyways happy coding.